# Getting the SQL script of the dataset in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

I'd like to display my SQL queries in a collapsible textbox in SSRS to avoid any misunderstanding.

Is there a way to retrieve the SQL script of the dataset to put it into the "expression" field of the textbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great question! This got me to do a little digging, because of a vague memory that this was exposed somewhere. Sure enough:

```
=DataSets("TopEmployees").CommandText
```

or, even better,

```
=DataSets("MyDataSet").RewrittenCommandText
```

The second option will include the parameter substitution.

Keep in mind this could lead towards security problems, if someone can find a SQL injection attack through this...

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255235.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried it in SSRS 2008 and it's a perfect solution there. However I am trying to do that in SSRS 2005 where it does not work. Any suggestions to make it possible under 2005?

Comment: I doubt it's possible in 2005. SSRS really hit its stride in 2008, the proverbial 3.0 release. (http://www.feld.com/wp/archives/2006/04/getting-it-right-with-version-30.html)